# Continuous Footnotes in InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, book

I'm having trouble how to place continuous footnotes to my work.

I'm working on a book and in every instance that I use footnotes for a spread, it always starts with 1.

Please help me how to fix this. If it is possible, whenever I place a footnote in each page it should continue with the numbering of the footnote before it. E.g. page 1 has footnotes 1 & 2, then page 3 has footnote 3, and so on.

Any help is much appreciated. I am a newbie in using InDesign and I need to finish this project within a week so I am freaking out. :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/941958?tstart=0):

> The continued numbering option only works for a continuously threaded
> text frame -- one long story spanning several pages. You probably have
> one single stand-alone text frame per page.
>
> Either make all the text
> frames into one long story -- you can link two frames together by
> clicking the Out-port of the first and then clicking on the next
> frame, and you can use any of ID's numerous page break codes and/or
> sryle options to have the story break to the next page or frame -- or
> fake the footnote numering by setting the style of the code in your
> text to something like .1 pts, No Color and entering the right number
> manually. The number in the footnote itself can simply deleted.

Comment: Yes, this is most likely OP's problem – as a self-professed newbie, the document probably consists of lots of unconnected text frames.